# How to INSERT INTO table DEFAULT VALUES

Tags: sql, sap-ase

When you want to insert default values into a table, some databases allow this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table DEFAULT VALUES;
```

ASE does not support this.

Using:

```
INSERT INTO table (col2, col3) 
VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

and skipping the identity column works for columns with constant default values, but not for computed columns including timestamp.

Introspecting the table for a column with a constant default and then just specifying `DEFAULT` for that column would work, unless it's a table with only an identity and computed columns, but no one is likely to use such tables.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: @Danny Stop. Flooding. Please.

Answer (score 3):

Skip columns with default values from the insert statement.
If a default value exists for the skipped column (or user-defined datatype of the column), it is entered.